Issue with Table of Contents not displaying in LaTeX document with customized section formatting
I have a document where I've modified the sections and subsections to appear within a colored frame. Now I want to include a table of contents, but nothing shows up when I use \tableofcontents. I'm attaching a Minimal Working Example (MWE). I don't want the section and subsection numbers to appear, as they currently do.
\documentclass[a4paper, openright, 12pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\xpatchcmd{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\sectionbox}{}{\PatchFailed}

\xpatchcmd{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\subsectionbox}{}{\PatchFailed}

\newcommand*{\sectionbox}[1]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}
                 [
                  colback=green!30,% background
                  colframe=green!100,% frame colour
                  coltext=black, % text color
                  width=\textwidth,%
                  height=0.7cm, 
                  halign=center,
                  valign=center,
                  fontupper=\large\bfseries,
                  arc=0mm, auto outer arc,
                 ]
    \MakeUppercase{#1}
\end{tcolorbox} 
} %


\newcommand*{\subsectionbox}[1]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}
                 [
                  colback=blue!20,% background
                  colframe=blue!80,% frame colour
                  coltext=black, % text color
                  width=\textwidth,%
                  height=0.7cm, 
                  halign=center,
                  valign=center,
                  fontupper=\large\bfseries,
                  arc=0mm, auto outer arc,
                 ]
    \MakeUppercase{#1}
\end{tcolorbox} 
} %


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage 

\setcounter{section}{0}
\sectionbox{Datos generales}

\lipsum

\subsectionbox{Evolución de calificaciones}

\lipsum


\end{document}


You're not using any \section or \subsection commands so there is nothing to show up in the ToC.

You are not actually using any \section or \subsection commands. All you do is use \sectionbox/\subsectionbox, which produces the format you want, but doesn't actually start a section or subsection.
If you use the sectioning commands instead, it works fine.
\documentclass[a4paper, openright, 12pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\xpatchcmd{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\sectionbox}{}{\PatchFailed}
\xpatchcmd{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\subsectionbox}{}{\PatchFailed}

\newcommand*{\sectionbox}[1]{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}
    [
    colback=green!30,% background
    colframe=green!100,% frame colour
    coltext=black, % text color
    width=\textwidth,%
    height=0.7cm, 
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    fontupper=\large\bfseries,
    arc=0mm, auto outer arc,
    ]
    \MakeUppercase{#1}%
  \end{tcolorbox}%
} 

\newcommand*{\subsectionbox}[1]{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}
    [
    colback=blue!20,% background
    colframe=blue!80,% frame colour
    coltext=black, % text color
    width=\textwidth,%
    height=0.7cm, 
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    fontupper=\large\bfseries,
    arc=0mm, auto outer arc,
    ]
    \MakeUppercase{#1}%
\end{tcolorbox}% 
} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage 

\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{Datos generales}

\lipsum

\subsection{Evolución de calificaciones}

\lipsum

\end{document}


Attempting to produce an image causes my editor to crash?!

Hi. Thanks, but, with your solution, section and subsection appears in titles an index.

@Á.Garzón Sorry, but I don't understand. I thought you wanted the section and subsection to appear in the table of contents. I'm not sure what you mean by 'titles an index'. Your example doesn't have an index, but you might mean the contents. But then what does 'titles' mean? Is it the numbers you don't want appearing at all? That is, you want basically \section* rather than \section?

@Á.Garzón Actually, I see you say something about numbers in your question. I read that earlier, but you also said they currently appeared and I couldn't see any, so there didn't seem to be any to remove.

@Á.Garzón If you want to eliminate the numbers, see edit. Adding \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} should do it. It seems to me not necessarily the correct way to do it, but I couldn't figure out how to easily get \section* to add a contents entry, so unless you also have sections you want numbered, this should do the trick.

Hello, sorry if I didn't explain myself well. The only difference I want to achieve with respect to my MRE is that I want the table of contents to appear. I don't mind if the section and subsection numbers appear in the table of contents, but I don't want them to appear in the headers of the sections and subsections.

Sorry again. I didn't see your edit. Now it works fine. Thanks you very much!

@Á.Garzón No problem. I did read it, but because they didn't appear when I compiled, I admit I forgot that part of the question. I don't think it makes sense to have numbers in the ToC if they don't refer to anything, but changing the numbering is fortunately an easy thing to do ;).
